# Speed control of three phase induction motor

Tags: induction-motor

We have squirrel cage type three phase induction motors in our plant. I am very interested to know the alternative method of VFD to control the speed of motor. Can I use a dimmer?
Moreover, how did people control speed of three phase motor then before the advent of VFD?

Comment: Why would you not want to use a VFD?

Comment: I will definately use a VFD, but i m interested to know How did people control speed of three phase motor  before the advent of VFD?

Comment: Many motors where DC due to this reason if speed had to be controlled.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no good, flexible way to speed control a three-phase induction motor without a VFD (or something very, very similar to a VFD).

Comment: Motor/generator systems with variable speed systems like the Ward Leonard drive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_Leonard_control can be used to generate variable frequency 3 phase AC. VFD is cheaper and simpler.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ward Leonard appears to be for DC motors. I mean, you could power an AC motor from an AC generator turned by a DC motor controlled by a Ward Leonard control, but I think it would be fair to ask, in that case, why not just drive the mechanical load with the DC motor and skip the AC generator and motor altogether? But I appreciate the comment because I didn't know about Ward Leonard until now.

Comment: @mkeith Location might be one reason : the induction motor is remote from the speed control system. (I'll admit it's a bit of an unlikely scenario!)

Comment: Charles Cowie mentioned an important point. The induction motor does not routinely spark, so it might make sense to put an induction motor in a more hazardous location and keep the rest of it somewhere else. Also, synchronous motors with different speeds or reduction gears could be kept in sync with each other from a single generator. If that synchronization is important for the overall machine design. So there could definitely be some uses.

Answer (score 3):

Before electronic VFDs were developed, the speed of wound-rotor 3-phase induction motors was controlled by schemes involving variable resistance inserted in series with the rotor windings or connecting the rotor windings to additional machines (Kramer and Scherbius drives). There were also schemes in which variable frequency was generated by driving an AC generator with some other type of variable speed machine such as a DC motor, eddy-current coupling drive, or a mechanical speed changer (continuous variable transmission).

In many cases, a DC motor, eddy-current coupling drive, or a mechanical speed changer was used to drive machines directly without using AC motors. However wound rotor motors could be built with higher power ratings than other machines, and could be controlled using a lower power rotor circuit control. That was one reason to use those schemes.

Variable-speed AC generator machines were also used to control large quantities of small synchronous motors used for making synthetic fiber. The first solid-state electronic variable speed drives were developed by Borg Warner under contract for DuPont for synthetic fiber spinning applications.

Also, small induction and brushless synchronous motors controlled that way could safely be installed in explosive atmosphere areas.

Before the invention of the transistor, vacuum tubes, mostly thyratrons, were used for variable-speed control of DC motors, eddy-current coupling drives, wound-rotor induction motor drives and perhaps some variable frequency drives.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several reasons to not use a VFD, and I do own and use VFDs.  First, they are expensive.  Second, they have to be connected directly to your mains (they must be connected to the live wires coming into your circuit breaker—never plug them into an outlet). Oh, and don’t assume you can connect it.  You need filters, and a bunch of other stuff.  Unless you are an electrician, we all have zero business trying to connect them. Third, VFDs typically give you way more options than you need, especially if you are just wanting to control motor speed.  Fourth, VFDs are the number one electricity polluters (for those who care—I don’t care).
Speak to an electrician.  You’d be surprised how frequently a VFD is NOT the industry standard for what you are wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

VFD meaning: Variable Frequency Drive (VFD) is a type of motor controller that drives an electric motor by varying the frequency and voltage supplied to the electric motor. Other names for a VFD are variable speed drive, adjustable speed drive, adjustable frequency drive, AC drive, microdrive, and inverter.

Can it run on a dimmer? the answer is YES, you can,

But:

- The dimmer only lowering your voltage without any compensation like increasing or lowering frequency.
- This can damage your motor because powering on a lower voltage than intended.
- The motor will be very difficult to control because is very load-depended.
- Can cause overheating the motor because running on lower voltage.
- It's not a recommended way to do it. You will likely break the warranty for your motor.

Comment: Thanks mate, very helpful it is. Adding a confusion, How did people control speed of three phase motor then before the advent of VFD?

Comment: It's like a dimmer but not dimmer like now (now is usually using TRIAC) back then we are using Autotransformer and later using Variable transformer (Variac) and you can expect the burning motor :)